# Add one spring project to another

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, build.gradle, dependency-management

I create one Spring project (let's say Project-A with gradle) as lib and in this project I configured some beans to include to another (let,s say Project-b also with gradle).
With help maven local repository (.m2 folder) I add one project to another, and in local this is work good, but

Project-B I want to dockerizing with help palantir plugin for gradle.

So, in docker, with springframework.boot plugin for gradle I include all dependencies in jar for docker.

But problem is, the beans, which are configured in Project-A not included in jar file for Project-B.

I, am also add springframework.boot plugin in Project-A, and publish this jar in local .m2 repo (and this is increase jar-file from project-A), but now, dependencies not added to Project-B.

How I can solve this problem?

My configs

Project-A (picstories-library)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

group 'org.picstories.lib'
version '2.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.allJava
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url '****'
            credentials {
                username '****'
                password '****'
            }
        }
    }

    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'org.picstories.lib'
            artifactId 'picstories-library'
            version '2.0-SNAPSHOT'

            artifact sourceJar {
                classifier "sources"
            }
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.modelmapper', name: 'modelmapper', version: '2.3.2'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.10.3'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch', version: '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive', version: '2.2.5.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '28.0-jre'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.10.3'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'

    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'

    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.2.5.RELEASE'
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '3.2.4'
    testImplementation group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest', version: '2.2'
}
jar {
    exclude 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA', 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.MF'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.picstories.Application',
                'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { "lib/$it.name" }.join(' ')
    }
}
```

Project-B (Parser-manager-service)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    id 'com.palantir.docker' version "0.22.1"
    id 'com.palantir.docker-run' version '0.22.1'
    id 'com.palantir.docker-compose'version '0.22.1'
}

docker {
    name "${project.name}:${project.version}"
    files 'build/libs/parsers-manager-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
    dockerfile file('Dockerfile')
    pull true
    noCache true
}


dockerRun {
    name "${project.name}"
    image 'parsers-manager-service:unspecified'
    ports '7003:7003'
    clean true
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'java-library-distribution'

group 'org.picstrories.parsers.manager'
version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.picstories.lib', name: 'picstories-library', version: '2.0-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-webflux', version: '2.2.5.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'io.projectreactor.kafka', name: 'reactor-kafka', version: '1.2.2.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka', version: '2.3.4.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch', version: '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive', version: '2.2.5.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '28.0-jre'
    implementation group: 'net.bytebuddy', name: 'byte-buddy', version: '1.10.9'
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.30'
    implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-core', version: '1.2.3'
    implementation group: 'org.yaml', name: 'snakeyaml', version: '1.25'
    implementation group: 'org.modelmapper', name: 'modelmapper', version: '2.3.2'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.10.3'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.10.3'


    testImplementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '5.2.1.RELEASE'
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '3.2.4'
    testImplementation group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest', version: '2.2'
    testImplementation group: 'io.projectreactor', name: 'reactor-test', version: '3.3.0.RELEASE'
}

distZip.shouldRunAfter(build)


jar {
    exclude 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA', 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.MF'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.picstories.parsers.manager.Application',
                'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { "lib/$it.name" }.join(' ')
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Dependencies from lib not importing

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem just add spring.factories file in lib and add path to config class with removing org.springframework.boot plugin